# Windows won't recognize network printer

Tags: networking, printing, printer, samba, network-printer

So this has been driving me crazy. I've set up a shared printer via Samba on Ubuntu using [this very helpful guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu). Everyone using a Mac can connect and print perfectly. Windows on the other hand will recognize the printer on the network, but as soon as you try to add it, it throws some sort of cannot connect error (the error differs slightly depending on how you try to add it, but has the same general message as seen below).

Adding printer by clicking on it from "network" folder:
[image]

Adding printer by going through the "add a printer" dialog and manually entering network address:
[image]

So pretty much what I want to accomplish is to get the darned thing to work on windows as well as OSX.

**UPDATE:** A different windows vista computer can connect to the print server and print. So either it's an issue with My computer, or with Windows 10.

**UPDATE 2:** A full restart allows me to add the printer. However, When trying to print to it it says that there was an error printing.

Comment: In the adding the printer to the network manually did you do the ip/the name of the printer? Im very curious on this one.

Comment: used ip address and hostname, same address. either way it was //hostname/printername (i didn't even have to type the printer name as windows recognized the host and put a dropdown with avalible printers on that host)

Comment: Well, it's solved (sort of). Turns out, windows 10 doesn't like samba for some reason. Connecting to the printer using an http CUPS address allows me to print... weird, but I'll take it

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find it, contact your network administrator. Click the Start button, and then, on the Start menu, click Devices and Printers. Click Add a printer. In the Add Printer wizard, click Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer.